# How do I get both the key and the value of a dictionary returned to ajax call

Tags: c#, ajax, dictionary

In my static web method I populate a dictionary with the Bankid and Bankname that I select from a database. The Id goes to the Key and the Value goes to the value part. SO there're approximately 20 key-value-pairs in my dictionary. Then I return this dictionary to my ajax call:

```
      $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'AJAX.aspx/Banks',
            data: '',
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (data)
            {
                $.each(data.d, function ()
                {
                    $("#testDiv").append(this.Key + " " +this.Value + "<br/>");
                });
            },
            error: function (x, e)
            {
                alert("The call to the server side failed. " + x.responseText);
            }
        });
```

In the above case I get 20 rows of undefined undefined. But if I remove both .Key and .Value from this I just get the value, so bank names. I need both the key and the value because I'm going to populate a select element with them-key for value and the value for inner html. 
 In case you want to see my webmethod, here it is:

```
    [WebMethod]
public static Dictionary<string, string> Banks()
{
    Dictionary<string, string> dict = new Dictionary<string, string>();
    DatabaseProvider provider = GetDatabaseProvider();
    provider.AddOutParameter("V_CUR", OracleType.RefCursor);
    DataTable dt=provider.SelectDataTable("AGAPUS.PAYMENT.SP_BANKS", CommandType.StoredProcedure);
    foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
    {
        dict.Add(row["PAYMENTTYPE"].ToString(), row["PAYMENTTYPEID"].ToString());
    }
    return dict;
}
```

Comment: If you look at the raw response from the web method does it have all the data you want in it? If so can you post the json here for us to see and play with?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks more like a question about jQuery to me.  That said, try changing your success function to:

```
success: function (data)
{
    $.each(data.d, function ( key, value )
    {
        $("#testDiv").append(key + " " + value + "<br/>");
    });
}
```

The key and value are passed as parameters to the function when evaluating a map.